# All javascript resources are failing to load after moving a MojoMotor site to a new server

Tags: php, javascript

I moved a MojoMotor site to a new host and the site broke. I know it has database access because if I change the database config options to something bogus, it gives me a connection error. Changing it back, the error goes away.

I also tried removing the .htaccess file in case it was causing problem. This had no effect.

I don't really understand Mojomotor and I'm not finding anything in the documentation to help. (Oddly enough, because the CodeIgniter documentation is wonderful)

**The page loads, but it is riddled with resource errors. Here's what's failing to load according to my inspector:**

**/javascript/load/jquery**

**/javascript/load_parse/login**

**/javascript/load/ui**

**/javascript/mojo/index**

*What am I missing?*

**NOTE: THE ERRORS SHOWN FOR THESE FAILED RESOURCES IS A 404 RESOURCE NOT FOUND ERROR**

Comment: check the server's access and error logs. it'll probably show a bunch of 404 errors for the various JS resources.

Comment: Actually they are 404 errors on those resources, not 500 errors. Sorry, should have been more clear that 'failed to load'. I'll update my question.

Comment: that why I said 404 errors... the 404 hit will get recorded in both logs.

Comment: Yes, there are a bunch of 404's. But I'm not sure how that helps me. I already knew that. What I can't figure out is what to do with them. Mojomotor has its own routing system, and so it's hard to track down why those aren't loading. The config.php has the correct url and home page set.

Comment: seeing what the actual on-disk file request is can help with backtracking the routing and finding the glitch.

Answer (score 0):

`I also tried removing the .htaccess file in case it was causing problem. This had no effect.`

Instead of removing it, I would check if it's working.

- Is the project same path as in the previous server? If it was in root folder, and now it's in a subfolder, this could be the problem.
- Has your new server the right Apache settings, like overwriting rules via .htaccess?
- There was any configuration setting outside the project folder? Redirections, Apache config files, etc.
- This may sound dumb, but did you check that the javascript files are in the right folder in the server?
- Did you check that you are including javascript files via relative and not absolute paths? Maybe there is something like a `basePath` variable hardcoded somewhere.